# Regular expression for format XX-XXXX

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression for format xx-xxxx can somebody help? It will take numbers and 
characters. I have no idea about regular expressions. also can some explain that how whole expression works?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that the string will be only containing exactly that string with no leading or trailing whitespace:
`/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$/`

If you need to find that pattern within another string (a paragraph?) you would use:
`/\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\b/`

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
\A[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}\Z
```

will also work.